# jQuery quickSearch / Live Search

Tags: jquery, wordpress, search, quick-search

I implemented the [jQuery quickSearch](http://bio.mq.edu.au/Tools/jquery/plugins/riklomas-quicksearch/examples/) (Example #1 with changes) into a WordPress template successfully, but for it to be really perfect I'll need help as to achieve what I want I have to tweak the jQuery part and that's not my strong suit.

In my header.php template I've got:

```
<?php if(is_post_type_archive('books')){
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/js/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('input#id_search').quicksearch('div#booklist div.cover');

        });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

And in my WordPress template (leaving out the query):

```
<form action="#" id="searchform"><div><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="s" class="search" id="id_search" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'enter title of the book you are looking for...';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'enter title of the book you are looking for...') {this.value = '';}" value="enter title of the book you are looking for..."/></div></form>

<div id="booklist">

<h4>Series Name</h4>

<div class="cover"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $ftimg; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="133" height="200" /></a>
<?php
echo "<br>";
the_title();
?>
</div>

<h4>Series Name #2</h4>

<div class="cover"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $ftimg; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="133" height="200" /></a>
<?php
echo "<br>";
the_title();
?>
</div>


and so on....

</div>
```

When I use the search by entering a book title now, not only this one book shows up as result but also all h4 headings do. 
My desired visual result would be that only the h4 heading of the book (i.e. the name of the series the book belongs to) and the book itself remain and all other h4 headings 'vanish' just as the rest of the books not matching the query do.

Comment: may be this will help you, 

    http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tIuBL,
    https://github.com/roparz/Light-Javascript-Table-Filter

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know the output.

```
    $(function () {
    $('input#id_search').quicksearch('div#booklist div.cover',{
        'show': function () {
            $(this).addClass('show');
        }
    });

    if($('div#booklist div.cover').hasClass('show') && $.trim($('#txtEmail').val()).length>0){
        $('.show').prev('h4').css('display','block !important');
        $('h4').css('display','none');
    }

    });
```

**NOTE:** Untested

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately now, all h4 headlines are hidden/don't display even before I enter anything into the search field.

Comment: Can you please try again ? And can I have look into your site ?

Comment: There might be some error ..If I can look in to your site, it would help me detecting this error ..

Comment: Site is in development, but I put together a test page w/ just the query: http://www.crocodesigns.com/jquery_test.php. This test page uses your latest code.

Comment: Can you please try again ? Change the code in in the above link so that I can see the result as well. And sorry for trouble :)

Comment: No trouble at all. I'm thankful for you taking the time to help me. I updated the code. Search works again, but all h4 headers are displayed again as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69371/discussion-between-rohil-phpbeginner-and-croco2511).

Comment: Can you please come to the chat ?